# Laravel Artisan Command Not Working while using from Code

Tags: php, laravel, console, laravel-artisan

I have created a laravel command as:

```
class CreateFirstUserCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'firsttenant:create {name}';
    protected $description = 'Creates first user in database with name';

    public function handle()
    {
        $name       = $this->argument('name');
        $website    = new Website();
        app(WebsiteRepository::class)->create($website);

        $hostname       = new Hostname;
        $hostname->fqdn = $name.'.site.me';
        $hostname       = app(HostnameRepository::class)->create($hostname);
        app(HostnameRepository::class)->attach($hostname, $website);

        $tenancy = app(Environment::class);
        $tenancy->hostname($hostname);

        // resolves $hostname as currently active hostname
        $tenancy->hostname(); 

        // switches the tenant and reconfigures the app
        $tenancy->tenant($website); 

        // resolves $website
        $tenancy->website(); 

        // resolves $website
        $tenancy->tenant(); 
        $tenancy->identifyHostname();
        sleep(10);

        $role       = Role::create(['name' => 'tenant']);
        $permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'all']);

        $user= new User();
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->email = 'admin@'.$name.'.site.me';
        $user->password = Hash::make('12344321');
        $user->assignRole('tenant');
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

I am calling this command from console as:

> php artisan firsttenant:create alpha

and works fine as expected but when I call this from code as:

> Artisan::call('firsttenant:create', ['name'=>$name]);

It doesn't perform any action.

Comment: Do you get an error? If not, I think it is called. Try adding a dump at the top of the handle method.

Comment: yes it's being called but it doesn't insert any record in database while calling it from console inserts data

Comment: The function doesn't realy do anything. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Jerodev it performs required operation while calling from console but not from code

Comment: add the complete code including where DB inserts happen

Comment: @Paras i have added the code

Comment: While executing `Artisan::call('firsttenant:create', ['name'=>$name]);` does the `$name` have value ?

Comment: yes i did($name) and it have a value